Dependency Registration with parameter in .net MAUI
I am migrating an application to .net MAUI and was using TinyIoC and AutoFac earlier in XF, however now we have decided to use the inbuilt  .net DI.
For MAUI in the MAuiProgram class I am registering all the interfaces and classes.
However when I load one of the page, I want to register one more dependency along with a parameter which is a object of model class.
I have one interface class:
public interface IStockAdjustmentConfiguration
{
}

Implementation of interface:
public class ModuleConfigurationData : ModuleConfigurationDataBase, IStockAdjustmentConfiguration
{
    public ModuleConfigurationData(List<DeviceSettingModel> theSettings) : base(theSettings)
    {}
}

Now to register the above interface and its implementation, I need to pass the input "List<DeviceSettingModel> theSettings", which i do not have when my app loads, this is available with me in the view model of a page.
How can i register my above interface and implementation, in the MauiProgram.cs file where i am building the builder?
Or
How can I register the above interface directly from the .cs page where i have the  the input "List<DeviceSettingModel> theSettings".
In XF this is how the code looked like and it worked
public StockAdjustmentModule(    
    List<DeviceSettingModel> Configuration,
    ISystemSetting systemSetting) 
    : base(Configuration, systemSetting)
{
    _configurationData = new ModuleConfigurationData(Configuration);
    Container.GetContainer().Register<IStockAdjustmentConfiguration>(_configurationData);
}


Could you elaborate more on what you want to achieve or add some relevant code in the question? Here is the docs, Dependency injection.

By the  way, does it help? Injecting services into view models in .NET MAUI app

@LiqunShen-MSFT: I have modified my query, hopefully this can help clear the confusion, and apologies for not being clear at first.

@Saurabh explain to me, why you HAVE TO use constructor parameter. Why you have to register myservice(param). Instead of just myservice(), and then in your VM call myservice.set(param)?

@H.A.H. Honestly, that is how the code was written and the same thing is getting called from multiple places, thus to avoid re-writing a lot of code, i thought of asking a query here, if at all that was possible, if registering a interface and class along with some parameter passing or from a view model page post the builder is built is not possible or doable, i will rewrite the code to have a parameter less constructor.

@Saurabh Do not change the service itself. Wrap around it, and inject the wrapper. This is basic initialization problem. I am not sure how well I am explaining this, however.

Example:
First: Instead of IStockAdjustmentConfiguration
You can make IStockAdjustmentConfigurationProvider
And we declare getter and setter for IStockAdjustmentConfiguration
And we register it in MauiProgram.cs builder.Services.Add<IStockAdjustmentConfigurationProvider, StockAdjustmentConfigurationProvider>();
Second:
In your ViewModels where you have the registration code, you replace it with the setter, so this:
Container.GetContainer().Register<IStockAdjustmentConfiguration>(_configurationData);

Becomes:
StockAdjustmentConfigurationProvider.Set(new IStockAdjustmentConfiguration(_configurationData));

Third:
Where you inject your service:
 SomeConstructor(IStockAdjustmentConfiguration config)
 {
     Config = config;
 }

Replace with:
 SomeConstructor(IStockAdjustmentConfigurationProvider provider)
 {
     Config = provider.Get();
 }

You do not have to re-write the class and the consturctor.
What I am saying is that you can wrap it inside your injected service.
It is not uncommon to have Singleton service, that gets initialized AFTER the program start.
